# Android AlarmManager sometimes triggers late if phone runs on battery

Tags: android, alarmmanager

*** Updated: The issue has likely been resolved. Please refer directly to the update below, as AlarmManager was only partially to blame. ***

I'm currently developing an android app with alarm clock functionality. Unfortunately it turned out that there seem to be rather specific cases for which AlarmManager doesn't seem to work as expected .

When I initially tested the app, I did so by means of the Android Studio Emulator (Nexus 5, API 21) as well as an old phone of mine (Galaxy S2, API 16), with the result that all alarms were delivered in time. As soon as I switched
to my Xperia Z1 Compact (API 19) though, alarms suddenly triggered minutes late occasionally.

Interestingly this seems to be the case especially when the phone is currently running on battery (i.e. not connected to the pc or an outlet). It kind of feels like AlarmManager would suddenly act super sluggish in a desperate attempt to spare the battery, completely oblivious to the fact that it was utilized by means of *.setExact()*. If the device is not asleep, delivery is always in time.

Either way, the behaviour that results from my code doesn't seem to be deterministic at all, which is what really boggles my mind.

Simplified version of my code:

First, I schedule AlarmManager depending on the API. According to the logs calendar is set to the correct date and time.

```
public abstract class AlarmScheduler {
    //...
    private static void schedule(AlarmManager am, PendingIntent pi, Calendar calendar){
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            am.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
        } else {
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

The pending intent that is scheduled is a WakefulBroadcastReceiver. According to the logs, every time the alarm is late the call of
*onReceive()* is as well, at least as far as I've seen. So it seems likely that the problem is located here.

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent service = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        service.putExtras(intent);

        startWakefulService(context, service);
    }

}
```

For completeness, this is the service that is started by the BroadcastReceiver. The activity that the service starts acquires its own wakelock in *onResume()*. I've also tried to forcefully delay the release of the receiver wakelock up to 1000 ms, in order to guarantee that one is active at all times, but that didn't yield different results.

```
public class AlarmService extends Service {
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Intent alarmDisplay = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmActivity.class);
        alarmDisplay.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        alarmDisplay.putExtras(intent);
        getApplication().startActivity(alarmDisplay);

        /** Some simple database operations here */

        AlarmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

I'm honestly kind of lost where I did go wrong here. But since an alarm clock that might trigger minutes late on some devices is not acceptable of course, I'd
really appreciate any input - thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Alright, so first of all AlarmManager.setExact() does indeed seem to deliver late occasionally, but only for seconds, not minutes. According to the documentation this seems to be intended, as it states:

> "The alarm will be delivered as nearly as possible to the requested trigger time."

Unfortunately this does sound like a matter of milliseconds rather than seconds, which is why I did assume that AlarmManager was behaving faultily in the first place . If it was evidently delivering seconds late, I thought it capable of delivering minutes late as well. Still, my mistake ultimately.

Secondly, the issue described initially was a wakelock issue that, at least in my case, did only show on my API 19+ phone when it was currently running on battery. While API 19 apparently introduced very aggressive power management for the sake of battery life, the management appears to be even more aggressive if the phone is running on battery. This seems also to be the reason why on the emulator everything was behaving normal (per default it is always in the process of being charged, if the icons are to be believed).

The problem with the code initially posted is that the receiver wakelock is released before the activity acquires its own wakelock in *onResume()*. Just a matter of milliseconds, but still sufficient for the CPU to be pushed back to sleep apparently. As I did state in my original post, I already thought of this as a potential source of the problem, which is why I did try to forcefully delay the release of the wakelock, in order to guarantee that at least one would be active at all times. For testing purposes I did this quick & dirty by means of *wait()* though, which the OS seemingly wasn't very fond of and thus forcefully shut down my service at some point, which was something that didn't show in regular logcat output. From this point on subsequent alarms tended to be faulty, although I'm not sufficiently knowledgeable in terms of Android to actually explain why.

Either way, the issue could be resolved by acquiring and releasing only one single wakelock instead of two separate ones (please mind that, due to the very nature of the problem, there is no absolute certainty, but testing results are looking fine).

Comment: Without even looking at your code, I'd suggest you run some tests with other (ideally official, or at least reputable) Alarm Clock applications on the troublesome device, and see if those occur on time.  You could also see if there's something in the SDK samples you could build and try for comparison.  The point being that either a) you are missing something b) there's a bug on these devices or c) there's an oddity on these devices which sophisticated apps work around but yours as yet does not.

Comment: @DerGolem Well, yes, but as far as I understand the whole purpose of setExact() is to schedule alarms accurately for the most part, despite these changes. I wouldn't care if the alarms would be off some seconds, but its minutes unfortunately.
It did also work fine on the API 21 emulator (although I don't know how closely the emulator simulates an actual phone).

Comment: Please put your own answer and close